# Python Tkinter GUI placement with grid

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How can I fix this? I'm trying to put the list of foods in the middle of the right side of the screen, but this is how it shows up. Why are food2 and food3 all the way down there and not just below food1?

[image]

I'm new to coding, and I'm kinda stuck here, but there aren't really many tutorials about what I'm trying to do.

```
from tkinter import *

food = ["food1", "food2", "food3"]

window = Tk()

window.config(background="#000000")

foto = PhotoImage(file="img.png")

label = Label(window,
              text="i stopped reading for this",
              font=('times new roman', 20, 'bold'),
              fg='orange',
              bg='#000000',
              relief=SUNKEN,
              bd=5,
              padx=10,
              pady=10,
              image=foto,
              compound='bottom'
              )

label.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=10)

b = IntVar()

for index in range(len(food)):
    radio_button = Radiobutton(window,
                               text=food[index],
                               variable=b,
                               value=index
                               )
    radio_button.grid(row=10 + index, column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because the label is tall.  Put all the radiobuttons in a frame and put that frame at row 10 column 2.

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: The label is in row 10, the second radiobutton is in row 11 - and therefore appears entirely below the label, that's what row numbers *mean*.  You could apply `rowspan=3` to the label so that it occupies all of the rows that the radiobuttons do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is food2 and food3 all the way down there and not just below
> food1?

It is because you set `Label` widget layout to `row=10` `label.grid(row=10,` . And also, you set `Radiobutton` widget layout to `row+index`.

So you want to do without Frame.
You need to add `rowspan` for both  `Label` and `Button` widget.

Snippet:

On line 24, change this:

```
label.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=10)
```

to:

```
label.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=3)
```

On line 34, change this:

```
radio_button.grid(row=10 + index, column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
```

to:

```
radio_button.grid(row=index, column=2, padx=10, rowspan=3, sticky=W)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> why is food2 and food3 all the way down there and not just below food1?

Grid is like a tabel:

- `food1` is in the same row as the label with the image in it, and the height of the row is the height of the label. `food1` is located in the middle of that row
- `food2` and `food3` are in their own rows. The height of the row is determined by the `Radiobutton` alone.
- The height of the `Radiobutton`s is smaller than the height of the image so there is uneven distribution of the rows.

To fix that, you can add a frame for the right side and add all the buttons to it:

```py
right_frame = Frame(window, bg="#000000")
right_frame.grid(row=10, column=2)

for index in range(len(food)):
    radio_button = Radiobutton(right_frame,
                               text=food[index],
                               variable=b,
                               value=index
                               )
    radio_button.grid(row= index, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)


window.mainloop()
```

**Note**, the `row` and `column` index start with `0`. You could replace the `row=10` with `row=0` and it will look the same. (You could do the same with the columns)

---

Another solution would be to set the `rowspan` argument of the `label` in `.grid()`:

```
label.grid(row=10, column=1, padx=10, rowspan=3)
```

and then leave the rest as it was:

```
b = IntVar()

for index in range(len(food)):
    radio_button = Radiobutton(window,
                               text=food[index],
                               variable=b,
                               value=index
                               )
    radio_button.grid(row=10 + index, column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)


window.mainloop()
```

- `rowspan` - how many rows will the widget span on.

You have 3 buttons you want to align next to the `label` so I set the `rowspan` to 3.